# How to show/hide div tags based on the selection of a radiobutton in a form

Tags: javascript, php, html, yii

I'm using two radiobuttons('reviewed' and 'not reviewed') in  search box to filter the values in admin.php. There are another two buttons('approved' and 'rejected') in search box which has to be displayed when **`'reviewed'`** is clicked and hidden when **`'not reviewed'`** is clicked.
 Below is the code of the search form.

```
<div class="row">
        <?php #echo $form->label($model,'ReviewedDate'); ?>     
                <?php echo $form->radioButtonList($model, 'ReviewedDate', 
        array('1' => 'Reviewed', '' => 'Not Reviewed')
    ); ?>
    </div>

       <div class="row"> 
                <?php echo $form->radioButtonList($model, 'Approved', 
        array('0' => 'Rejected', '1' => 'Approved')
    ); ?> 
    </div>
<div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Search'); ?>
    </div>
```

How can I display the second div based on the review/not reviewed button of first .
within the search form.

Comment: Are we supposed to magically know what your PHP classes do ?

Comment: You should at least show what you've tried. Your problem is a very basic jQuery task - so please spend a couple of minutes and try to figure out a solution.

Comment: @MichaelHärtl Since it is a search form, I need to show/hide div tags before I submit the form. This is where I'm stuck

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Javascript for that, have a look at the HTML that your code is generating and hook the radio buttons with the appropiate Javascript functions to show or display the other elements